# pagination not displayed in woocommerce plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, woocommerce

Navigation arrow keys for pagination are not displayed in products page. I have used woocommerce plugin in wordpress 3.4.2 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will not be visible till you have enough products to have 2 or more pages.

Answer (score -1):

Can't remember why this happens. I think its because wordpress posts per page is set to 'n' in your settings so woocommerce follows that setup (only showing 'n' number of products)
Anyway to fix it open your functions.php file and insert:
 add_filter('loop_shop_per_page', create_function('$cols', 'return 4;'));